# Destination /etc/default/kubelet does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, vagrant, kubelet

I am trying to install kubernetes cluster with vagrant and ansible and it does not work. 
As the error message, I've got:

```
TASK [Configure node ip] *******************************************************
fatal: [k8s-node-3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Destination /etc/default/kubelet does not exist !", "rc": 257}

RUNNING HANDLER [docker status] ************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
k8s-node-3                 : ok=10   changed=8    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

The vagrant file:

```
IMAGE_NAME = "ubuntu/bionic64"
Nodes = 3


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 1024
        v.cpus = 2
    end

    config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |master|
        master.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
        master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.100", name: "vboxnet0", adapter: 2 
        master.vm.hostname = "k8s-master"
        master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.playbook = "k8s-setup/master-playbook.yml"
            ansible.extra_vars = {
                node_ip: "192.168.99.100",
            }
        end
    end

    (1..Nodes).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "k8s-node-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.#{100 + i}", name: "vboxnet0", adapter: 2 
            node.vm.hostname = "k8s-node-#{i}"
            node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                ansible.playbook = "k8s-setup/node-playbook.yml"
                ansible.extra_vars = {
                    node_ip: "192.168.99.#{100 + i}",
                }
            end
        end
    end

end
```

and the master-playbook.yml file

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install packages that allow apt to be used over HTTPS
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg-agent
      - software-properties-common

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Docker
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
      state: present

  - name: Add apt repository for stable version
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
      state: present

  - name: Install docker and its dependecies
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - docker-ce 
      - docker-ce-cli 
      - containerd.io
    notify:
      - docker status

  - name: Add vagrant user to docker group
    user:
      name: vagrant
      group: docker

  - name: Remove swapfile from /etc/fstab
    mount:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      fstype: swap
      state: absent
    with_items:
      - swap
      - none

  - name: Disable swap
    command: swapoff -a
    when: ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes
    apt_key:
      url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
      state: present

  - name: Adding apt repository for Kubernetes
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: kubernetes.list

  - name: Install Kubernetes binaries
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet 
        - kubeadm 
        - kubectl

  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}

  - name: Restart kubelet
    service:
      name: kubelet
      daemon_reload: yes
      state: restarted

  - name: Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm
    command: kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.99.100" --apiserver-cert-extra-sans="192.168.99.100"  --node-name k8s-master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

  - name: Setup kubeconfig for vagrant user
    command: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
     - mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.kube
     - cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /home/vagrant/.kube/config
     - chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.kube/config

  - name: Install calico pod network
    become: false
    command: kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.4/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml

  - name: Generate join command
    command: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
    register: join_command

  - name: Copy join command to local file
    local_action: copy content="{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest="./join-command"

  handlers:
    - name: docker status
      service: name=docker state=started
```

and the node-playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install packages that allow apt to be used over HTTPS
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg-agent
      - software-properties-common

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Docker
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
      state: present

  - name: Add apt repository for stable version
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
      state: present

  - name: Install docker and its dependecies
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - docker-ce 
      - docker-ce-cli 
      - containerd.io
    notify:
      - docker status

  - name: Add vagrant user to docker group
    user:
      name: vagrant
      group: docker

  - name: Remove swapfile from /etc/fstab
    mount:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      fstype: swap
      state: absent
    with_items:
      - swap
      - none

  - name: Disable swap
    command: swapoff -a
    when: ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0

  - name: Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes
    apt_key:
      url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
      state: present

  - name: Adding apt repository for Kubernetes
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
      state: present
      filename: kubernetes.list

  - name: Install Kubernetes binaries
    apt: 
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet 
        - kubeadm 
        - kubectl

  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}

  - name: Restart kubelet
    service:
      name: kubelet
      daemon_reload: yes
      state: restarted

  - name: Copy the join command to server location
    copy: src=join-command dest=/tmp/join-command.sh mode=0777

  - name: Join the node to cluster
    command: sh /tmp/join-command.sh

  handlers:
  - name: docker status
    service: name=docker state=starte
```

What is wrong? Why the kubelet file can not be found?

Comment: Please remove those line and try again.

Answer (score 12):

The error occurs, because `/etc/default/kubelet` does not exist on the VMs. Add `create: yes` to the "Configure node ip" tasks in `master-playbook.yml` and `node-playbook.yml`, so that they look like this:

```
  - name: Configure node ip
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/default/kubelet
      line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}
      create: yes
```

This way, the file will be created if it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [generic ansible-playbook](https://github.com/gcgirish-radisys/Vagrant_K8s/blob/master/kubernetes-setup/node-playbook.yml) I see at git that generally follows the [official manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/). Initially, it was created (half year ago?) for ubuntu 16.04. I tried to run (instructions from official manual) against ubuntu 18 (as you using bionic), but I should say, there is no `/etc/default/kubelet` installed (`after apt install ...`).

**Update:**

And [here is why](https://github.com/kubernetes/release/pull/672)...

P.S.
I would suggest using Kubespray as local vagrant/kubernetes setup, but it's because it just works from the box.

Comment: It depends on what you what achieve. Install kubernetes on vagrant using ansible or debug your type of instal?

Answer (score 1):

You are following the tutorial on [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/15/kubernetes-setup-using-ansible-and-vagrant/).

I got the same error as you:

> "Destination /etc/default/kubelet does not exist".

Just look at the instructions [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/).
You need to adjust the playbook slightly to the other instructions:

- Change the line: `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.50.10" --apiserver-cert-extra-sans="192.168.50.10"  --node-name k8s-master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16"` according to the other instruction to `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.50.10"`

The result will be a join command that you need to register and re-use to join the two worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error last time:

```
TASK [Configure node ip] 
*******************************************************
fatal: [k8s-master]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Destination 
/etc/default/kubelet does not exist !", "rc": 257}
```

So please check your ansible-playbook and verify that the kubelet will be installed. If not please add create parameter:

```
create: yes
```

So in your case, it should look like this:

```
- name: Configure node ip
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/default/kubelet
    line: KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip={{ node_ip }}
    create: yes
```